# Access EXIF data from file uploaded with Paperclip in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

Can I safely use `self.image.staged_path` to access file which is uploaded to Amazon S3 using Paperclip ? I noticed that I can use `self.image.url` (which returns https...s3....file) to read EXIF from file on S3 in Production or Development environments. I can't use the same approach in test though.

I found `staged_path` method which allows me to read EXIF from file in all environments (it returns something like: `/var/folders/dv/zpc...-6331-fq3gju` )

I couldn't find more information about this method, so the question is: does anyone have experience with this and could advise on reliability of this approach? I'm reading EXIF data in `before_post_process` callback

```
before_post_process :load_date_from_exif

def load_date_from_exif
  ...
  EXIFR::JPEG.new(self.image.staged_path).date_time
  ...
end
```